# WPF Datagrid cell button image not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Using the following XAML i am trying to add a button with image on it in a datagrid cell. The button will delete the row upon click

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="32">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="Delete">
                <Image Source="../Images/cross.png"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The button is added and deleting the row if clicked. But the image is not shown. I have tried many ways but none is working. I also placed the image in the same directory in which the XAML file is placed but even then no success.

Anyone have any idea about how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you set the image `Build Action` property to `Resource`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the image and go to it's properties and change it's type to Content.